# PowerShell - XML Array Issue

Tags: xml, arrays, powershell

So I wrote a powershell script to read in an xml file, parse through it, and output to a file after its been cleaned up. My issue is that as it loops through the foreach loop it is storing it all to the same variables.

```
#Access the XML file
[xml]$XML= [xml](Get-Content $XmlPath)

foreach ($node in $XML.catalog.entry)
{
    #XML Variables
    $Username = $XML.catalog.entry.username 
    $Description = $XML.catalog.entry.description
    $Service = $XML.catalog.entry.service

    #Creating the syslog event that will be sent to SecureVue
    $writeOutput= "Username : [$Username] Description: [$Description] Service: [$Service]"

    #output
    $writeOutput
}
```

Unfortunately, the output I keep getting it:

```
Username : [User1 User2 User3 User4] Description: [Description1 Description2 Description3 Description4] Service: [Service1 Service2 Service3 Service4]
Username : [User1 User2 User3 User4] Description: [Description1 Description2 Description3 Description4] Service: [Service1 Service2 Service3 Service4]
Username : [User1 User2 User3 User4] Description: [Description1 Description2 Description3 Description4] Service: [Service1 Service2 Service3 Service4]
Username : [User1 User2 User3 User4] Description: [Description1 Description2 Description3 Description4] Service: [Service1 Service2 Service3 Service4]
```

Instead of:

```
Username : [User1] Description: [Description1] Service: [Service1]
Username : [User2] Description: [Description2] Service: [Service2]
Username : [User3] Description: [Description3] Service: [Service3]
Username : [User4] Description: [Description4] Service: [Service4]
```

I know i need some variation of:

```
foreach($node in $XML.ChildNodes)
```

But I can't seem to get it to work. Any ideas on how to write out each line with the one array position for each node in the array?

Thank you!

Comment: Please add a sample of the input so we can see the schema.

Answer (score 1):

As @Eris said, a sample of your XML file would make this easier to test, but at a glance, this part might be a good place to start:

```
foreach ($node in $XML.catalog.entry)
{
    #XML Variables
    $Username = $XML.catalog.entry.username 
    $Description = $XML.catalog.entry.description
    $Service = $XML.catalog.entry.service

    ...
}
```

It looks like you're assigning these variables properties of the collection of nodes, when your intent is likely to assign properties of the individual nodes.  I'd try something like this, instead:

```
foreach ($node in $XML.catalog.entry)
{
    #XML Variables
    $Username = $node.username 
    $Description = $node.description
    $Service = $node.service

    ...
}
```

i.e. you want the properties of `$node`, not `$XML.catalog.entry` for the variables inside the loop.